# An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.

Tags: vb.net-2010

please am trying to apply for a request from my website that am working on and l got this error:
`Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The 'CalCulateClaimForDeath' procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead.`

The Source Error pointed me to this code:

`Line 239:
Line 240:        //finally, execute the command.
Line 241:        int retval = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Line 242:
Line 243:        // detach the SqlParameters from the command object, so they can be used again.`

Help is needed.thank you